# how do i convert html edited text in C# loop to fully formatted text on the page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a list of strings that i would like to display in cshtml page (Asp.net C#) ,the problem is  instead of having html tags in my text i want to display the text formatted on the page when i run the website.
the output is: `<p><strong>some </strong><i>data</i></p>`
it should be:  **some** *data*

this is the C# code in cshtml page:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>@item.content</div>
        }
```

Comment: the `code` tag, indicated in the doc does not work?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`Html.Raw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) so it renders as `IHtmlString` in HTML instead of `string`.

```
<div>@Html.Raw(item.content)</div>
```

> Rendered HTML

```
<div><p><strong>some </strong><i>data</i></p></div>
```

Comment: Can't be thankful enough ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace HTML codes and tags with empty text using regex.
[Click here to verify regex](https://regex101.com/r/Xf1FOQ/1)

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@Regex.Replace(item.content, "<.*?>", String.Empty)</div>
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).